# Change certain values in XML based on if else condition in mule

Tags: xml, if-statement, mule, transform

I am getting xml file/s from an FTP and then mapping the data to a webservice call..I need to change certain fields in XML file based on if else conditions. Here is the sample input file (only part of xml):

```
 <MATMAS>
     <MSGFN></MSGFN>
     <ZPLD2></ZPLD2>
 </MATMAS>
```

If `MSGFN` is `003` then I need to map `0` to `isActive` field in webservice input, if not then `1` and condition for `ZPLD2` is:

```
case
  when @zpld2='' then null
  when @zpld2='00000000' then null
  else @zpld2
end.
```

Can i achieve this in data mapper when mapping the xml to webservice input? If so can you please guide me. I am very new to Mulesoft. Let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: Your question would be more readable if you separated text from code more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with Datamapper using xpath expressions and lookup tables. See here for more info: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/33X/DataMapper+Transformer+Reference and look for the sections xpath and lookup tables.

Comment: Hi Ryan...thanks for the reply...I was able to get the first condition using ""IsActive = (input.MSGFN == '003') ? '0' : '1' ;"" in the data mapper script....I am not able to get the second one, for ZPLD2 (case
  when @zpld2='' then null
  when @zpld2='00000000' then null
  else @zpld2
end.) Can you please help me on this...Thanks

Comment: I tried using PlannedPriceDate = ((input.ZPLD2 == '' || '00000000') ? null : (input.ZPLD2));  but it is throwing java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1